# C99 compiler for Ms-Dos?

Tags: c, dos

Are there any c compilers for ms-dos that support some C99 features? 
I have trouble searching for recent compilers that I can run on my system.
Actually, I need this to have a compiler on my Playbook via Dos Box, while I am away from home and wihout internet access.

Comment: Do you have to _run_ the compiler in DOS? Or is it enough to make a cross-compiler that runs in another environment but generates DOS executables?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I need the one that runs on DOS and produces executables to run in DOS.

Comment: I think compilers stopped supporting DOS somewhere during the mid 90s, so it seems unlikely that you would find one, especially since C99 was regarded with a lot of scepticism upon release and it took many years before it became accepted and implemented on the PC compilers.

Comment: @lundin, Do you have any references for why C99 was regarded with a lot of skepticism? I am interested in reading more about it.

Comment: @Shahbaz It was mainly because they decided to leave some compatibility with C90 and C++ behind, but also because the new standard introduced a lot of poorly-defined behavior. And many questioned the use of some new features like the complex number library. Many in the standard committee itself were not happy with the outcome. [Microsoft has decided to not implement C99](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/05/vs_c99_support/) in the Visual Studio compiler, as one example. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241080/what-is-the-point-of-the-c99-standard) is another link on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This compiler should work on MSDOS (gcc adapation)

http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/C/dos-gcc/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

[CC386](http://ladsoft.tripod.com/cc386_compiler.html) supports C99. But it requires a 386.