# Why doesn't GNOME use C99?

Tags: c, coding-style, c99, gnome, c89

Looking at [mutter source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/mutter/tree/src/core/core.c) and [evince source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/evince/tree/libview/ev-jobs.c), both still use C89 style of declaring all variables at the very beginning of the function, instead of where it is first used (limited scope is good).  Why don't they use C99? GNOME 3 was launch recently and mutter is quite new, so that could have been a good opportunity to switch, if the reason was compatibility with old code style.

Does that mean that contributing code to GNOME needs to be written in C89?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303502/why-do-new-c-books-not-adhere-to-the-c99-standard/2303506#2303506

Answer (score 4):

The rationale can be linked to the same rationale behind Glib and GTK+:

- No C99 comments or declarations.

> Rationale: we expect GLib and GTK+ to
>   be buildable on various compilers and
>   C99 support is still not yet
>   widespread.

Source: http://live.gnome.org/GTK+/BestPractices

Comment: Odd how they make this claim, then include all kinds of non-portable assumptions and code all over the place without proper configure checks...

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of scope, I guess you can still do this:

```
if (condition)
{
  int temporary = expression();
  trigger_side_effect(temporary);
}
```

In other words, each actual brace-enclosed scope can contain new variable declarations, even in C89. Many people seem surprised by this; there's no difference from this perspective between a function's top-level scope and any other scope contained therein. Variables will be visible in all scopes descending from the one that declared them.

Note that I don't know if this is supported by the GNOME style guide, but it's at least supported by C89, and a recommended technique (by me) to keep things as local as possible.

Comment: A perfectly good idiom, but every new programmer is bitten in the butt by (a) trying to use `temporary` after the block closes and (b) doing the same when `temporary` was shadowing a variable from up-scope so that it *appears* to work, but not the way they expect.

Answer (score 1):

Many people consider declaring variables all over the place, as opposed to at the beginning of the block, bad style. It makes it mildly more work to look for declarations, and makes it so you have to inspect the whole function to find them all. Also, for whatever reason, declarations after statements were one of the last C99 features GCC implemented, so for a long time, it was a major compatibility consideration.

Comment: I've been writing C for 25yrs, and have gone back and forth on the best way to declare variables. What I've arrived at is a style where they are used in for loops when used mostly or exclusively to count the loop out, and where you don't want to draw attention to housekeeping. Otherwise it's generally better to declare them up top where they are easy to find - usually a type followed by all the variables of that type to keep things clean and not use up too much vertical space on the screen.

Comment: The general rule for me is to use stylistic touches to draw attention to what is important and keep housekeeping in the background. One of C's greatest features is the ability to use functions return values as arguments to a function. It's done extensively in the C library and to good effect.